# ransack gem - integer value -- undefined method 'gsub' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

I am using the Ransack gem to perform searches on the database.

The problem is that if the column is of type integer and the predicate used is 'contains', am getting

```
undefined method 'gsub' for 2:Fixnum
```

Any idea on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Which ransack gem version you are using ?

Comment: version 0.7.2, that's the latest I could find

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching an integer column using Ransack, the 'equals'(eq) predicate is required. Ransack doesn't support partial matching of integers. The gem's creator recommends using a ransacker to cast the column to a string if you wish to do so, as seen in this comment:

https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/190#issuecomment-13232486

Unfortunately, he does not elaborate on how to do so.